# Good Ajax framework for Java EE

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, dojo

I'm relatively new to Java EE and I'm in need of a framework that will simplify AJAX for me.

At the moment I have code that uses the dojo toolkit to draw a graph, but I'd like to have the graph updatable via AJAX. is there a good framework that allows me to do Ajax call backs and insert and run javascript into a page?

If so is there a good tutorial on how to use this framework?

My only experience with Ajax is using Telerik under ASP.Net.

Answer (score 2):

[Dojo does AJAX too](http://www.dojotoolkit.org/book/dojo-book-0-9/part-3-programmatic-dijit-and-dojo/ajax-transports/errors-and-timeouts).

Normally I'd recommend [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) for this kind of thing but you're already using Dojo so you should probably use that. The two can be used together however, if desired.

Answer (score 0):

There are some JSF component libraries that got more or less ajax support. [ICEfaces](http://www.icefaces.org/main/home/) for example, makes all the standard components ajax'ish and offers server push techniques. Check out the [jsfmatrix](http://www.jsfmatrix.net/) to get an overview.